# Quarkus >= 0.18.0 fails to build if default values provided in configuration

Tags: java, quarkus

We built an app with 0.18.0 quarkus version and we have following `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.datasource.url=${POSTGRES_DATABASE_URL}                                                                                                                                                                      
quarkus.datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver                                 
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update                                
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect         
quarkus.http.port=${PORT:8080}                                                  

%dev.quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db                                      
%dev.quarkus.datasource.driver=org.h2.Driver                                    
%dev.quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

When I tried upgrading to 0.20.0 (or any version higher, including 1.0.0.Final) I get following error when building with maven:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.20.0:build (default) on project thats-my-spot: Failed to build a runnable JAR: Failed to build a runner jar: Failed to augment application classes: For input string: "${PORT:8080}" -> [Help 1]
```

Why?

`${PORT:8080}` just means that it should take either the `PORT` environment variable if available or use `8080` if not.

I looked at potential issues, changes in semantics but found only one bug that might touch defaults in properties: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3030 But the description and solution is different, so I don't think that it broke my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with 1.2.1.Final? We had some issues with handling defaults of environment properties at some point but it has been solved for quite a while.

If you can reproduce it with the latest, please open an issue in our tracker with a reproducer and we will have a look.

Comment: I somehow missed testing it in 1.2.1.Final, and it works, thanks :)